# How to pass term guid to CSWP through query string

Tags: 2013, term, cswp, kql

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.itunity.com/article/introduction-sharepoint-search-queries-explained-117) on how to use kql to query against terms.

I've set up a page with a content search web part and in the query builder I've entered this

```
owstaxIdLocation:GP0|#ad491ed9-c21c-46d9-896c-c0d148957c60
```

Items tagged "Mumbai" from the example on the tutorial. In the result source there are items tagged with that and they are returned. Good.

Now I want to get fancy and pass the value in a query string parameter. So I change my query builder to

```
owstaxIdLocation:{Querystring.locationtag}
```

It kinda seems to work, but if I try and put the GP0!# (or the other prefixes like GPSet|#) it breaks. I tried encoding the param value for example

```
?tag=GP0%7C%2362417a66-e677-4ede-8823-58cdd764e7e4
```

Any idea how to include a full term in the query string parameter for use by a CSWP in a KQL query?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the value in query string like this:

```
locationtag=%230TermGUID*
```

replace TermGUID above with the guid of the Term

Comment: I owe you a drink man for this one.